# Bootstrap Styling A JQuery/Java Pop-up Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a filter box which is displayed when you click a filter icon but this is non-bootstrap styled.  I am in the process of upgrading the website using Bootstrap3 HTML5.

Currently the filter icon looks like the below

[image: Current pop-up]

But we want it styled as:

[image: Wanted pop-up]

My code is below which is the old styling but i'm not up to scratch on styling Jquery/Java

```
document.getElementById('<%:cell.ColumnIdentifier%>_link').addEvent('click', function()
    {
        if(filterPopUp == null){}
        else
        {
            filterPopUp.hide();
        }
        filterPopUp = new StickyWin.PointyTip("Add filter for <%:cell.Value %>", "<%= String.Format("Values from <input id='{0}_from' name='{0}_from' value='{1}'/> &nbsp;to <input id='{0}_to' name='{0}_to' value='{2}'/><br/><div style='text-align:right !important;margin-right:0px;margin-top:5px;'><input type='button' onclick='SubmitForm(this, \\\"filter\\\");' id='{0}' name='{0}' value='Apply' style='margin-right:10px;background-color:#CCCCCC;text-align:center !important;' class='greyButton89'/><input type='button' onclick='SubmitForm(this, \\\"clear\\\");' id='{0}' name='{0}' value='Clear' class='greyButton89' style='background-color:#CCCCCC;text-align:center !important;'/></div>", cell.ColumnIdentifier, defaultMin, defaultMax)%>", {
        point: 'up',
        pointyOptions: { theme: 'light' },
        relativeTo: '<%:cell.ColumnIdentifier%>_img'
        });
        
        return false;
    });
```

The code I used to do the mock is:

```
 <div class='col-sm-4 hidden-xs'>
        <div class='panel panel-default'>
            <div class='panel-heading'>
                <h3 class='panel-title'>Add filter for Test</h3>
            </div>
            <div class='panel-body'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label class='col-sm-5 control-label'>Amount from</label>
                    <div class='col-sm-7'>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">£</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label class='col-sm-5 control-label'>Amount to</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">£</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group pull-right'>
                    <div class='col-sm-12'>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default'>
                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> Apply
                        </button>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default'>
                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Clear
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

First question can it be done?

Second question if yes, how?

Thanks

Antony

Comment: Post your entire old page, on the filterPopUp = [..] missing some code at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Max.  I have updated my current code section above to display my full bit of code of this section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, hovewer maybe must move some code to the page element where this popup is attached, can you post the relevant html code where this popup is attached ?

```
document.getElementById('<%:cell.ColumnIdentifier%>_link').addEvent('click', function()
    {
        if(filterPopUp == null){}
        else
        {
            filterPopUp.hide();
        }
        filterPopUp = new StickyWin.PointyTip("<div class='col-sm-4 hidden-xs'><div class='panel panel-default'><div class='panel-heading'>                 <h3 class='panel-title'>Add filter for  <%:cell.Value %></h3>             </div>", "<%= String.Format(" <div class='col-sm-4 hidden-xs'>         <div class='panel panel-default'>                          <div class='panel-body'>                 <div class='form-group'>                     <label class='col-sm-5 control-label'>Amount from</label>                     <div class='col-sm-7'>                         <div class='input-group'>                             <span class='input-group-addon'>£</span>                             <input type='text' class='form-control' id='{0}_from' name='{0}_from' value='{1}'>                         </div>                 </div>                 </div>                 <div class='form-group'>                     <label class='col-sm-5 control-label'>Amount to</label>                     <div class='col-sm-7'>                         <div class='input-group'>                             <span class='input-group-addon'>£</span>                             <input type='text' class='form-control' id='{0}_to' name='{0}_to' value='{2}'>                         </div>                     </div>                 </div>                 <div class='form-group pull-right'>                     <div class='col-sm-12'>                         <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' onclick='SubmitForm(this, \\\"filter\\\");' id='{0}' name='{0}'>                             <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> Apply                         </button>                         <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' onclick='SubmitForm(this, \\\"clear\\\");' id='{0}' name='{0}' value='Clear'>                             <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Clear                         </button>                     </div>                 </div>             </div>         </div> </div>      ", cell.ColumnIdentifier, defaultMin, defaultMax) %>", {        point: 'up',
        pointyOptions: { theme: 'light' },
        relativeTo: '<%:cell.ColumnIdentifier%>_img'
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: thanks for this @Max but the '"Add filter for <%:cell.Value %>",' is the header bit and this is the bit i'm struggling with as you've got the '<div class='col-sm-4 hidden-xs'><div class='panel panel-default'><div class='panel-heading'><h3 class='panel-title'>Add filter for Test</h3></div>' sat within the '"<%= String.Format("' section so I have 2 headers.  Other than that it works and looks perfect

Comment: @murday1983 have you see my new response ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  Yes the above worked.  Had the make some minor adjustments.  Thanks for the help @Max